# upload file through curl with php

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to upload a file through REST to my database. Here is the html file(this is just a test) which is able to do the job:

```
<form name="ZRXPupload" method="post" action="http:...." enctype="multipart/form-data">

  File = <input type="file" name="file" accept="text/*" value="File" /> 
  FormatType = <select name="formatType">
  <option selected="selected">ZRXPV2R2</option> 
  </select>  
  <input type="submit" value="Upload file" formtarget ="_blank"/>
</form>
```

Since I need to hide my REST (http) address, I use php (server side code)to do this job instead of uploading file directly to REST, see the code:

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $post = array(
      'file' =>'@'. $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],
     'formatType'=>'ZRXPV2R2'     
    );

$url = "http:........";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookies.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookies.txt');
//this is to get the session cookie with my user name and pass word and it works fine.

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('content-type:application/octet-stream'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;

curl_close($ch);

 }

?>
```

I searched a lot codes about this question, most of them are very similar with the above codes. but none of them works in my case. I really have no idea what is wrong here.
Could anyone give me some suggestions? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you see any errors if you put var_dump(curl_error($ch)) after curl_exec (before closing the session)?

Comment: @  Mateusz Drankowski      I used "echo (curl_exec($ch))", which said "import failed".I tried var_dump(curl_error($ch)), got the message: string(0) "". What does this mean? the uploaded file is empty? Really appreciate your response. I am a newbie in php, please help me more... thanks.

Comment: got it,  string(0) "" means error message is empty, then what's the problem?